# In chef custom resource how to specify that a key value pair is mandatory

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

While writing custom resources in chef we define attributes, their type, their default value and whether they are mandatory to be specified or not, e.g.

```rb
attribute :plugin,        kind_of: String, required: true
attribute :after_plugin,  kind_of: String, required: false, :default => 'pam_unix.so'
```

Suppose I need to take an attribute that is a Hash like

```rb
attribute :after,    kind_of: Hash, required: false, :default => {:search_interface => nil, :search_control => nil, :search_plugin => nil}
```

Here I have mentioned `required: false` which means it is not mandatory for user to provide the Hash.

I need to specify that if the Hash is given, then the `:search_interface` is mandatory

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining attribute (now named property), you can define callbacks that validate the user input.

See https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/cb4ee84e418164e8d2e85147efad711a42ff2799/lib/chef/resource/chef_gem.rb#L28 for an example.

In your case, you could write:

```
attribute :after,  kind_of: Hash, required: false, 
  :default => {:search_interface => nil, :search_control => nil, :search_plugin => nil},
  :callbacks => {
    "Must contain search interface" => proc { |v| 
      v.has_key?(:search_interface)
    }
  }
}
```